# Should i move my erc20 token to main network?

Tags: tokens, private-blockchain

i recently created a token in ropsten test network and was successful. Now i am going to create a real time token in one of my private network.

My question is, can i go ahead creating the same in private network itself or should i create only in main network?

Because in future i want to issue the tokens as loyalty points to my users which they can exchange for real ethers and monetize. Can i achieve this in private network itself? I am not sure of the differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your private network is, well, private. It is only accessible to the nodes which are connected to it and you probably don't have many nodes connected. It wouldn't probably be accessible for exchanges and token holders.

If you want "real" usage for the tokens then you either need a big & stable private network or just use the Eth mainnet. Also it's probably a lot easier (but still not easy) to get your tokens listed on exchanges if they are on the mainnet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick clarification. But will i get monetized if i host in a big private network? Or still i have to do in main network? Also hosting in main network makes me spend some ethers for each transaction if my token right? How will the exchange value of my token be determined?

Comment: Monetization and value depend on supply and demand. There is no explicit value set for tokens - if people want to buy them, price goes up. As I said, it's probably a lot harder to get your tokens listed in exchanges with a private network. If it's not listed in exchanges, the only option is to exchange it for Ether, and for that you need to be on mainnet also. And yes, you have to pay tx fees in mainnet with real Ether.